# yii dataprovider sorting

Tags: sorting, yii, limit

i have a question about sorting in Yii DataProvider. I want to sort it excatly like im doing it now, but starting with 3rd record DESC. Not first, second, but third record. Something like "limit => '3' criteria. Any ideas?

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('News', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
        'order'=>'create_time DESC',
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the [`offset`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#offset-detail) property on the criteria:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('News', array(
    'criteria' => array(
        'order'  => 'create_time DESC',
        'offset' => 2, // zero-based index, third record = 2
    ),
    'pagination' => array(
    'pageSize'   => 10,
    ),
));
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Nothing changed after adding offset => 2. Any other ideas?

Comment: figured it out - pagination must be false, and limit must be set.

Comment: @SebastianKoziara: But do you want the pagination or not? Also, I can now see why it won't work but it seems that it would report 2 less items if `offset` is 2? Can you confirm?

Comment: I don't need pagination. It just doesn't work when you got pagination set. Doesn't matter how many items you have.